# How do I make the code Wait for a few milliseconds in C#?

Tags: c#, xna, collision, game-physics

I have made some collision if statements, but they didn't work.

```
        birdbox3.X += 5;
        birdbox3.Y -= 5;

        if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner1)) {

            birdbox3.Y += 10;

        }
        else if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner2)) { 

            birdbox3.Y = -birdbox3.Y; }
```

So if we take the first statement, the box is initially on the left down corner. According to my code, it would ideally be going right+up in my game, once it hits the banner on the extreme top, it should go down+right, thus both the X and the Y positions will increase. But what happens is that is starts bouncing really fast, after debugging I realised it was forever stuck in the first if, it's almost as if it collides 2 times, reverting Y to its initial movement, colliding a 3rd time, and doing the process over and over.

Which brings us to the question, how can I make the Update code run a tad bit slower, or after half a second or such passes, so when it runs, it doesn't misinterpret collisions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use Thread.Sleep()

Comment: @Jamaxack Nope, would freeze up Game's thread. I don't think you want to lock up your game each time your object is updated. Think of it as freezing your UI in a winform/WPF app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `Update` method definition (If you have a regular `GameComponent` or `DrawableGameComponent`) , you'll notice you have access to the `GameTime`: 

`public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)`.

You can use that variable to trigger the collision only after a set amount of time. To do that, surround everything by a big `if` which checks the time elapsed:

```
private int elapsedTime = 0; //Declared at class level

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // We add the time spent since the last time Update was run
    elapsedTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

    if (elapsedTime > 500) // If last time is more than 500ms ago
    {
        elapsedTime = 0;
        birdbox3.X += 5;
        birdbox3.Y -= 5;

        if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner1))
        {
            birdbox3.Y += 10;
        }
        else if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner2))
        {
            birdbox3.Y = -birdbox3.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

In that case, the collision code is run only once every 500 milliseconds.

We need to add the elapsed time each time `Update` is run. Then, when we exceed the threshold, we run the collision bit and reset the timer to 0.

We need the local variable because `ElapsedGameTime` only knows how much time was spent *since the last Update*. To carry that number on multiple updates, we need to store it somewhere.

---

I also encourage you to take a look at [MSDN's Starter Kit: Platformer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx). You can find the download links at the bottom. There a *lot* of info that can be take from that, like effective screen/input management or a basic physics engine. In my opinion, it's the best thing from the official documentation.

Comment: @Zee I forgot the `ElapsedGameTime` reset on each call. Edited my answer to take that into account, I added a local variable to store the total time (which is reset each time we go over the arbitrary 500ms).

Comment: @Zee I also added a link to a damn good tutorial from MSDN. They have the source code included, one of the best things to learn XNA.

Comment: Thanks! I understand how it exactly works now, code is compiling pretty well, but it appears my problem was elsewhere, thanks for the help though, I'm really happy to have learned this.
I'll make sure to check the tuto as well! You rock